# How to get a distinct date count of Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
     id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
     name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     location VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
     postedDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
)
```

I want to retrieve a daily count of how many users are there for Distinct postedDate - how can I do that ?

This is SQL Server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would work.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, postedDate) AS postedDate, COUNT(*)
FROM user
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, postedDate)
```

By converting to `postedDate` to `DATE`, it removes the time component and thus allows you to group by just the date component.

Comment: You'd want the first field in the `SELECT` to be `CONVERT(DATE, postedDate)`, not `Name`.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg -- You're right.  Updated.  I was too lazy to do a fiddle to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONVERT(DATE, postedDate)) AS PostedDate,
    COUNT(CONVERT(DATE, postedDate)) AS DailyCount 
FROM userVid 
GROUP BY postedDate;
```

Comment: This answer isn't right. roryap's answer groups by `CONVERT(DATE, postedDate)`, whereas yours groups by `postedDate`. If you have one record for 10:00, and another record for 11:00 on the same day, then with your grouping, they won't appear in the same group, and your count will be wrong. Additionally, your use of `DISTINCT` may cover it up and make it less apparent that something's wrong.